# How to use subquery inside cmd parameters in SQL commnad?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows, sqlcommand

I have the code shown below where I'm trying to insert certain values into the database based on the user input. I need to validate user input and that's why I use a SQL command for insertion.

I can run this using SQL adapter but that doesnt seem to be efficient way since I need to make lot of validations for the user input.....

Problem:

I'm new to this C# and I dont know how to use subquery in the cmd parameters. Could anyone let me know how to make the below code working ?

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Insert these values?", "Confirm Insert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Insert INTO " + schemaName + "[TableLogic]    (Logic_Formula,Logic_InputsCount,Logic_Inputs,Logic_ConvFactorID) VALUES (@formula, @inputscount, @inputs,  @conversionfac)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@formula", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Formula.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputscount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numeric_inputscount.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputs", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Inputs.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@conversionfac", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "(Select ConversionFactorID FROM " +    schemaName + "[ConversionFactors] WHERE [conversionFactor_CF] =" + comboBox_ConfacValue.Text + " AND    [ConversionFactor_Desc] = '" + combobox_conversionDescription.Text + "')";

    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("New Rule is Inserted Successfully.");
}
```

Comment: For SQL Server use stored procedure!

Comment: Best you look at how to use ADO.NET and c#. There are plenty of how to articles out there or follow along examples. Once you understand the basics of how to query then write a new method in your class that can fetch the value of `conversionfac` and set that as the value for the `@conversionfac` parameter. IE. break your problem into smaller parts.

Comment: @Igor I agree with your comments... I can create a SQL command for getting values for "@conversionfac" and then use that in the code... I just wnat to explore will that be the only way ? coz its breaking the problem but increasing the line of code used...

Comment: @GowthamRamamoorthy - you can but you have to do it in the command text and not in the parameter. Parameters are always single valued or represent a table in itself but could never be an expression/sql to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In fact if you could, that would open your code up to massive [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. This is also why you shouldn't use any user input directly in any SQL queries (in other words, the whole reason you're using command parameters is to avoid this kind of thing).

You can convert this to be a stored procedure instead as Marciej Los [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142028/maciej-los), but if you're looking for something quick and dirty, this should work as well:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    @"DECLARE @conversionfac INT;" +
    @"SELECT @conversionfac = [ConversionFactorID] FROM " + schemaName + "[ConversionFactors] WHERE [conversionFactor_CF] = @conversionFactor_CF AND    [ConversionFactor_Desc] = @combobox_conversionDesc;" + 
    @"INSERT INTO " + schemaName + "[TableLogic]    (Logic_Formula,Logic_InputsCount,Logic_Inputs,Logic_ConvFactorID) VALUES (@formula, @inputscount, @inputs,  @conversionfac)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@formula", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Formula.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputscount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numeric_inputscount.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputs", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Inputs.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@conversionFactor_CF", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox_ConfacValue.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@combobox_conversionDesc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = combobox_conversionDescription.Text;
int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("New Rule is Inserted Successfully.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with the form of `INSERT INTO` you are using right now. You could use something like the following

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO tablelogic 
    (Logic_Formula,Logic_InputsCount,Logic_Inputs,Logic_ConvFactorID) 
    SELECT @formula, @inputscount, @inputs, ConversionFactorID
    FROM conversionfactors 
    WHERE conversionfactor_cf = @cfcf and conversionfactor_desc = @cfdesc"

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@formula", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Formula.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputscount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numeric_inputscount.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputs", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = textBox_Inputs.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cfcf", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox_ConfacValue.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cfdesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 160).Value = combobox_conversionDescription.Text;
```

This is another form for the select statement, where you can select your data to be inserted in a table from another table. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) for the details.